# Connection refused on Azure Redis Cache

Tags: redis, azure-redis-cache

From my managed web server, I am trying to connect to my Azure Redis Cache. From my web space, I use this php script:

```
<?php

$redisHost = 'yyy.redis.cache.windows.net';
$redisPort = 6379;

$redis = new Redis();

try {
    $redis->connect($redisHost, $redisPort);
    $redis->auth('xxx');
    echo 'Connected to Redis successfully!';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Failed to connect to Redis. Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

From `phpinfo()` I know that `redis` is indeed enabled on the server. But when I execute the above php script, I get: **Connection refused.** Notice that yyy and xxx are definitely correct.

My Azure Redis Cache is up and running. I have also activated the non-SSL port 6379.

What else could be the problem?

Comment: The "Connection refused" issue when connecting to Azure Redis Cache from a PHP script may be due to firewall restrictions, network security group rules, misconfigured SSL settings, or authentication problems. Ensure correct network configurations, verify access keys, and check for SSL/TLS compatibility. Debugging output and monitoring Azure Redis Cache status can help identify and address the specific cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my hosting provider blocked port 6379.